# G5 quad core will not boot from Ubuntu CD

Tags: boot

I have a PPC G5 Quad Core with Leopard on one hard drive and I want to install Ubuntu on a second hard drive.   The second drive is installed and formatted as a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) drive.

I have had no success booting from a CD or DVD with various PPC versions of Ubuntu using any of the suggested keys such as "C, Option, or anything else.  Booting into open firmware doesn't work as the system can't find the \install\yaboot file.

I am using various CD's burned as iso disk images, but none will boot.  I have reset the PRAM, etc, to no avail.   Beginning to get very frustrated.   Can someone shed some light and provide me with a command line in open firmware that will work, or else direct me to a confirmed PPC bootable version of Ubuntu please?

I'd appreciate any help you can provide....

Answer (score 0):

Only you can workout the openfirmware command as this depends on how your CD drive is connected.  The 12.10 PPC Lubuntu desktop/live ISO has a patch that should allow you to boot using the option/alt key on any CD drive.  If you want to install an earlier version then go via usb https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#How_do_I_boot_from_a_USB_drive.3F .  This http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2051337 method is pretty fool proof.